# How to remove white borders from images?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: How do I remove the white borders on my custom images?]

**Note:** To clarify this is not just a button issue as the circle is a background image with the same issue.

These were exported with transparent backgrounds so I don't understand the white borders.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()

window.option_add('font', 'Impact 19')

window.title("Randomizer")

window.geometry("600x900")

back =Canvas(window, bg="#172E38", height=2000, width=1000)


# ----RANDOM SELECT GEN--------
def random_gen():
    Champ = ['Aatrox',
             'Zoe']
    Lane = ['top', 'bottom', 'middle', 'support', 'jungle']
    Build = ['AD', 'Tank', 'AP', 'Crit', 'Attack speed', 'Assassin']

    x = random.choice(Build)
    y = random.choice(Champ)
    z = random.choice(Lane)

    return (x, y, z)


# TEST FUNCTION-------------
def random_display():
    result = random_gen()
    label.config(text=result, bg="#172E38", fg="#C49E4E", font=1000)


# Background----------------

C = Canvas(window, borderwidth=0)
filename = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/wrped/OneDrive/Desktop/button44-01.png")
background_label = Label(window, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=25, y=174)

# -----BUTTON---------------


label = Label(window, text="", font=1000, height=1, width=41, bg="#172E38")
label.place(x=120, y=425)

button = tk.Button(text="Goodluck!", command=random_display, font=500, borderwidth=-5, relief=FLAT)
img = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/wrped/OneDrive/Desktop/button1t-01.png")
button.config(image=img)
button.place(x=188, y=613)

button = tk.Button(command=window.quit, borderwidth=0)
exit = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/wrped/OneDrive/Desktop/exit-01.png")
button.config(image=exit)
button.place(x=228, y=690)

C.place(x=200, y=200)

back.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

P.S. I'm new here I don't know what to do this is simple to explain I can describe this in a ton of text and it won't let me post because there's too much code  - so if someone can give me tips for future posts that would be great!

Comment: Do proper code formatting please. Press Ctrl+K to select and mark as code, and dont use `>` for code

Comment: try adding an argument to your button as `borderwidth=0` or like `button = tk.Button(text="Goodluck!", command=random_display, font=500, borderwidth=0, relief=FLAT)`

Comment: you can try `highlightthickness=0`

Comment: no luck on any of these solutions. thanks for the help though!

Comment: [Here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.html) is the link to button documentation, youll find something useful there

Comment: if you use `Canvas` then you could use `c.create_window(...Label...)` instead of `place()` - or better `c.create_image(... PhotoImage...)` . In current code you create `Canvas` but you never use it - so it is useless.

Comment: first you could create minimal working code with your problem - you don't need `random_gen` (with long list) and `random_display` to show problem. Shorter code is easier to test.

Comment: Please reduce the code down to a [mcve]. I'm sure if we can duplicate this with 150 "champs", we can probably duplicate it with 1. Plus, if the question is about a border around an image, we don't need any other widgets except for the one with the image.

Comment: im new to this coding I didn't want to post a piece of code and have people tell me "it doesn't work because you don't have this" I just started learning python on Monday so ill try my best to make it "workable" while cutting it down in size.

Comment: *Both* [`Button`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190511024508id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) and [`Label`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429181150id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/label.html) widgets have a `bd` or `borderwidth` option that controls the width of a border drawn around them.

Comment: to change background color you could use `window['bg'] = '#172E38'` instead of `canvas`. On Linux I get borders on `Canvas` and I can remove them using `Canvas (..., border=-1)`

Comment: to have button without boder you can use `Label()` with `label.bind("<Button-1>, function)` instead `Button()` and `command=function` and you will have clickable `Label`

Answer (score -1):

You can easily remove white borders from your image using Adobe Photoshop.
I do not want to reinvent the wheel so you can go [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-remove-the-white-border-around-an-image-without-using-photoshop), or you can also use [this](https://www.tuxpi.com/photo-effects/borders) border editing software.

Comment: I made these in illustrator with 0 borders. This is something happening within the code. Thanks though!